# Class diagram - Confused about UML association multiplicity

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

I am little confused about how multiplicity works.

Let's i have a system where the user signs up, fills details about themselves and after signing up they have to fill details separately about their relative.

**My question :**

I want to indicate that for every User class there is only one Relative class and same backwards.

But what if there are many Users objects and each one is connected to their Relative class

so shouldn't the association be 1..* ?

Answer (score 4):

> But what if there are many Users objects and each one is connected to their Relative class

That's exactly what your diagram says: each User instance (or object) **must** have one, and only one, Relative object associated with it.

> so shouldn't the association be 1..* ?

If the multiplicity was `1..*`, then you're allowing one instance of a User to have multiple instances of Relatives associated with it. But that's not what you want, right? So it's correct to specify the way you did.

Comment: It’s even stronger: every User object MUST have exactly one Relative object. "CAN have" would be 0..1

Answer (score 2):

> every User class there is only one Relative class and same backwards.

This sentence is probably the root cause of your confusion. You actually modeled the following:
for every **instance** of `User` class there is only one **instance** of `Relative` class and same backwards.